# Logitech SetPoint software button remapping

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, button-remapping, logitech-mouse

My Logitech G5 Laser mouse has 9 buttons but it's SetPoint software only allows 5 of them to be used as "mouse buttons" and the remaining 4 can only be assigned special windows functions (Forward, Back, Cruise Up, etc) or Keystroke Assignments.  Many of the games I play will take up to 10 "MOUSE BUTTON" inputs for in-game actions but wont recognize the remaining 4 buttons even when assigned keystroke assignments.  Is there a way to make these last 4 buttons "Generic Buttons" as well as buttons 3,4,and 5? (1 is left click and 2 is right click).

My other question is if the above is not possible, maybe I can use AutoHotkey to remap keystrokes as assigned by my SetPoint software to mouse button commands?  If so how?

Answer (score 6):

Try [UberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/), it unlocks the additional keys in setpoint, at which point you can then use autohotkey to create whatever you may want. (For example, tilting the mousewheel right now fires F14, a key I don't have, which AutoHotKey uses for many things, depending on focused application)

You can even remap left and right click to sensitivity changing, and middle click to shut down, if you really wanted!

Comment: I had planned on asking how to rig setpoint + autohotkey to do Win + Shift + Tab for the 'thumb wheel' on my MX Revo.  UberOptions is great.  Another nice thing about it, it finally removes all the added profiles that I kept deleting, but kept coming back after every restart.

Answer (score 1):

Windows only supports up to 5 mouse buttons Left, Right, Middle, XButton1, and XButton2. That's why you can only configure 5 of them as mouse buttons. If you are configuring the rest to send keystrokes but they aren't showing up in games them you might be able to use autohotkey for that, however, autohotkey does simulated keyboard input to work so it might not do anything.

You can try autohotkey's SendInput, SendPlay, or SendEvent and see which one works for your games. Each one simulates keyboard input slightly differently.

For example, F12 was set to be sent by one of my mouse buttons

```
$F12::SendPlay {F12}
```

The $ disabling that hotkey being triggered by sending the same key again.